# conjugation: やあります vs やります

Tags: conjugations

When conjugating yaru to yarimasu, does it become やあります or やります?

Comment: What does "conjugating yaru to arimasu" mean?

Comment: I think you may have made a fundamental misunderstanding here. Can you explain your understanding of the difference between ある and あります?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically speaking, やあります is just plain wrong. It never conjugates to やあります.

Such a spelling may be used when someone said やります with a strange intonation (like "I wiiil dooo it"), but it should be rare.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you mean yarimasu instead of arimasu. Arimasu comes from aru (to be). ある -> あり -> あります

やる yaru conjugates to やります yarimasu.

やあります in romaji is yaarimasu, which would be stretching the "a" sound for no reason.

Masu-form conjugation simply involves changing the u hiragana to its i counterpart and then adding masu for godan verbs (yaru -> yari -> yarimasu), or dropping the ru and then adding masu for for ichidan verbs (taberu -> tabe -> tabemasu). The irregular verbs, suru and kuru turn to shimasu and kimasu.

Godan verb examples:

> いく to go -> いき -> いきます, not いいきます
>
> かう to buy -> かい -> かいます, not かあいます
>
> まつ* to wait -> まち -> まちます, not まあちます. Note that つ changes to ち since they are in the same row of the hiragana table.
>
> よむ to read -> よみ -> よみます, not よおみます
>
> さす* to hold up (eg. an umbrella) -> さし -> さします, not さあします. Note that す changes to し since they are in the same row of the hiragana table.

Ichidan verb examples:

> みる to see -> み -> みます, not みいます
>
> ねる to sleep -> ね -> ねます, not ねえます